# Getting actions to fire with backbone

Tags: backbone.js

Iv'e set up my first little backbone app with a router to see if i can get some actions firing.  I can't.  I don't get an error message, but the console.log messages aren't displaying.  Is there something more I have to set up to get the app started?

```
window.BreakfastApp = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: { "": "interest",  "products/:type": "products"},
  initialize: function(){    
    console.log("hello world");
  }, 
  start: function(){
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});     
  },
  interest: function(){
    console.log('interest')
  },
  products: function(type){
    console.log('product' + type )
  },
  toppings: function(){
    console.log('toppings')
  },
  results: function(){
    console.log('results')
  }
}));

$(function(){ 
 BreakfastApp.start(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) says:

> During page load, after your application has finished creating all of
>   its routers, be sure to call Backbone.history.start(), or
>   Backbone.history.start({pushState: true}) to route the initial URL.

In your case something like:

```
var BreakfastAppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    ...
});
var router = new BreakfastAppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

should do the job.